# vb.net wont retrieve data using htmlagilitypack

Tags: vb.net

Any ideas why it doesn't seem to retrieve innertext from this code

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim webGet As New HtmlWeb
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = webGet.Load("https://www.fakeaddressgenerator.com/")

    Dim work As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/strong/input")
    RichTextBox1.Text = work(0).InnerText
End Sub
```

I wanted to retrieve lets say the innertext value of "Street" from fakeaddressgenerator.com. Tried with this code but nothing was scrape, shows blank only on my richtextbox. Thank you for your answers

[See image from here for the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap5mp.png)

Comment: From Review: Please edit your question and post the code as text instead of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not in InnerText, it's in the Value of the "value" Attribute

```
work.First().Attributes("value").Value
```

Note: for First to work you need to `Imports System.Linq`

Comment: This seems to be helpful, but what if I want to get the value of City, State, etc. How should I implement it? And I don't get about the "First", where did you get that from? I'm sorry for asking too much, just wanted to have an idea on how this really works, its useful for future reference.

Comment: I just tried getting the value of the phone number, by just changing the xpath value to where the xpath value of phone number. It seems to work without Imports System.Linq

Comment: One last thing if you don't mind. How can I get the value of SSN, birthday, etc on the above table of Address table. Trying to get xpath from table above, seems to be getting an error

Comment: `work` is a collection, i.e. more than one node and your path quoted was pointing all the way to the end input tag that contained the value tonthere would only be one element in the collection, but it's a collection nonetheless, so we need to retrieve the first element, and that's what First does

Comment: It's kinda like buying loose tomatoes in a bag; the bag either contains one tomato or many, but they're still in a bag. First takes the first tomato out of the bag, the bag being the collection and the tomato being the html node (thing you want)

Comment: Be aware that parsing html like this I bu it's nature fragile - the slightest change to the page and it all stops working..

Comment: I get what you mean by being specific with the nodes, but I'm still new on this htmlagilitypack, thus can't really comprehend much about this code. Like for instance, the xpath doesn't have "value" but instead I want to get the innertext or so under <strong>, would you mind checking my other queries on this one.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234663/vb-net-how-to-get-value-of-strong-using-htmlagilitypack