# vb.net how to get value of <strong> using htmlagilitypack

Tags: vb.net

How to get value under  using hhtmlagilitypack. by the way there are many`<tr><td>` from this site, so would be much better if I can get the specific value under this "Social Security Number"

```
<tr><td><span>Social Security Number</span></td><td><strong>524-23-6748</strong></td></tr>
```

I tried using this code but no luck

```
 Dim webGet As New HtmlWeb
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = webGet.Load("https://www.fakeaddressgenerator.com/World_Address/get_us_address/city/Chicago")

    Dim work As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/strong")
    TextBox1.Text = work.First().Attributes("value").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is different to the last; the xpath is right except for the tbody. It's important to remember that the document  inspector you see in a browser might not reflect the actual source, and the source is what HAP parses

[image]

Easiest way I find to debug these is to remove the trailing part of the path and look what I get in the locals window:

[image]

In terms of how to know if it's attibute values or inner text etc, that comes from looking at the structure of the HTML:

[image]

Yellow highlights are attributes (things between `<` and `>` that is in the form `name="value"` is an attribute name/value pair), red underlines innertexts (anything between `>` and `<`)

---

All in your code is right apart from the TBODY, and that you're trying to select the Value of an attribute called "value" but your `strong` doesn't have any attributes, it only has an inner text

Comment: I'm sorry, really can't quite catch up on you regarding on what you just explained. Would you mind showing the code that would show how to get the value of example the full name, because on the upper table which has the full name, ssn, etc. seems no value, only shows <tr><td><strong> whatsoever. From there will analyze it how the code works.

Comment: Look in the Locals window I screenshotted and doodled on. HTML documents are like a tree. You can see in the code I selected the `.../table` node into the `work` variable, so I then switch to looking in the locals window at the work variable...

Comment: Work is a collection (of one item: the table), so i expand the results view to see all the items in the collection (just the table). Then I look in the table's Child Nodes, which is *also* a collection, so I expand *that* results view and I can see that "table" thus directly contains 6 "tr". Your code was trying to get the "tbody" but there simply isn't a tbody inside the table, in the object that HAP has parsed.. It skips from table straight to tr - 6 of them. Can you see how I'm using locals window to probe the structure of the object I get back? This helps write more code

Comment: Yes, I can see there are 6 "tr" on the table. But looking at your doodle, still have no idea on how to get specifically which item like "SSN" or anything on the table I like to extract innertext. I'm new in coding, just self taught. Your diagram, your debugging whatsoever is still complex for me to understand. Really sorry for that and really appreciate your time replying on me

Comment: Each of those tr can be expanded, and they have child nodes, which can be expanded and have child nodes etc.. I only took this screenshot to highlight the original point that your path isn't working because it contains `/table/tbody/tr[6]` and the html and the HAP document tree (locals window) don't have a tbody. You can map what you see in the locals window into an xpath; expand tr(3) - in the path that would be tr[4] (cos the locals window starts at 0 but the xpath starts at 1) so for debugging your problem I started removing bits from the end of the xpath and rerunning until it started

Comment: working, and then I used the locals window to start expanding again (working back towards the wanted value)  and making note of what I needed to access via xpath. An html document is a tree, the locals window is a tree. The names of properties etc that you see in locals are things that you can write in code, like the Attributes collection having 3 things, one called "value" with a Value of the street address etc so it means one can write `work.Attributes("value").Value` cos I saw it in the locals window

Comment: It might help if you start out looking at the locals window using something simpler: a parsed HAP document could be hundreds of nodes deep

Comment: This is my current code right now, but gives me an error.
https://imgur.com/a/AXGGqGu

Comment: As for the local windows, how can view that one or so? Mind giving me a headsup on how to start access the locals window or so

Comment: Debug Menu (when running a program) >> Windows >> Locals. Note that you'll have to be stopped on a breakpoint for the locals to be available. Locals is "the variables local/accessible to the current code context". To put a breakpoint click to the left of the line numbers so a red dot appears. Now as the ode runs if it hits that point it will stop and you can inspect the values of all the variables etc. I'm not sure why your code has an xpath of only `"/table/tbody/tr[6]"` - that's he fragment I removed. As an xpath it won't work because the document doesnt start from a `/table` (and no tbody)

Comment: Dim work As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/tr[6]")
        TextBox2.Text = work.First().Attributes("value").Value

tried using this code, still gives error to me

Comment: I'm confused; I mentioned that I removed some bits from the end of the xpath, and you keep quoting xpaths with ever more bits removed from the start? xpath is like a file path. you tried `/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/strong` and it was "file or directory not found", so you can come up some levels - `/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]` - not found.. `/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody` - not found, go up some more...Go up til it works, then locals to go down

Comment: Finally was able to get the xpath using chropath in chrome extension
`Dim webGet As New HtmlWeb
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = webGet.Load("https://www.fakeaddressgenerator.com/World_Address/get_us_address/city/Chicago")

        Dim work As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[6]//td[2]//strong[1]") 'SSN
        TextBox2.Text = work(0).InnerText`

Comment: It wasn't really about that, it's about using tools like the locals window to understand the relationships between objects in your program. That xpath there is a relative one and could match multiple nodes. it's good that it works for you now, but it feels a little bit like you're not really taking in what I'm saying, you're just casting around for anything that you can paste in and get working by trial and error. Here's an expanded locals window starting from `/html/.../div[2]`. Take a look at how the object tree relates to the xpath: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPwbx.png